# PHP if else statement using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, if-statement

I'm generating our Events pages using SimpleXML. Some of the Events take place only on one day while others occur repeatedly. I'm stuck trying to write an if-else statement.

If there's a repeating event, `repeatRuleID` will equal 1. If not, it will equal 0 (and the event takes place only once).

My question is, how can I edit the code below to say, for example, "through July 15" OR "on August 1" (obviously using the XML dates).

Here is my [page](http://bit.ly/lWR39p), XML ([single](http://bit.ly/kS76z3) and [repeating](http://bit.ly/micRJe) events) and code:

```
<h3><?= $event->title ?></h3>
<p><strong>
    <? if ($event->repeatRuleID=1): ?>
        through <?= $event->repeatUntilDate ?>
    <? else: ?>
        <?= $event->beginTime ?>
    <? endif; ?>
</strong></p>
<p><?= $event->locationText ?></p>
```

Comment: I am guessing this is a typo: `($event->repeatRuleID=1)` and it should be `($event->repeatRuleID==1)`

Comment: I updated the page with `$event->repeatRuleID==1` - unfortunately this doesn't return "through <date>" on repeating events. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what it does then?? keeps outputting the begin time?or nothing at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `$event->repeatRuleID=1` should contain 2 `=` like `$event->repeatRuleID==1`, as your assigning a value which always evaluates to true, you not to use the comparison operator to check the value's